# Opening an Excel File in Python Disables Dynamic Arrays

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, export-to-excel

I have an excel workbook that uses functions like OFFSET, UNIQUE, and FILTER which spill into other cells. I'm using python to analyze and write some data to the workbook, but after doing so these formulas revert into normal arrays. This means they now take up a fixed number of cells (however many they took up before opening the file in python) instead of adjusting to fit all of the data. I can revert the change by selecting the formula and hitting enter, but there are many of these formulas it's more work to fix them than to just print the data to a text file and paste it into excel manually. Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

I've been using openpyxl to open and save the workbook, but after encountering this issue also tried xlsxwriter and the dataframe to excel function from pandas. Both of them had the same issue as openpyxl. For context I am on python 3.11 and using the most recent version of these modules. I believe this issue is on the Python side and not the Excel side, so I don't think changing Excel settings will help, but maybe there is something there I missed.

## Example:

I've created an empty workbook with two sheets, one called 'main' and one called 'input'. The 'main' sheet will analyze data from the 'input' sheet which will be entered with openpyxl. The data will just be values in the first column.

In cell A1 of the 'main' sheet, enter =OFFSET(input!A1,0,0,COUNTA(input!A:A),1).
This formula will just show a copy of the data. Since there currently isn't any data it gives a #REF! error, so it only takes up one cell.

Now I'll run the following python code to add the numbers 0-9 into the first column of the input sheet:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('workbook.xlsx')
ws = wb['input']
for i in range(10):
    ws.append([i])

wb.save('workbook_2.xlsx')
```

When opening the new file, cell A1 on the 'main' sheet only has the first value, 0, instead of the range 0--9. When selecting the cell, you can see the formula is now {=OFFSET(input!A1,0,0,COUNTA(input!A:A),1)}. The curly brackets make it an array, so it wont spill. By hitting enter in the formula the array is removed and the sheet properly becomes the full range.

If I can get this simple example to work, then expanding it to the data I'm using shouldn't be a problem.